# HYG vs JNK Popularity and Quality

Tags: mutual-funds, etf, bonds, index-fund

Why is HYG more popular than JNK (respective AUMs are 20B and 13B) even though JNK has a lower expense ratio (0.49% and 0.40%, respectively)? It even seems that JNK's tracking error is lower than HYG's? I haven't been entirely convinced by the only source I found discussing this online.

Comment: What are the historical returns? Does HYG make up for extra fees with excess returns?

Comment: In my case, it's because of (lack of) brokerage fees.  I can only afford to buy a few hundred dollars per month, so even a $3 flat fee would be 1% of my investment.  That would require 10 years of lower fees to make up the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't tend to hand out surveys so it is tough to be sure, but much of the difference in popularity is probably due to history.  MarkIt's iTraxx was the biggest player in price data for credit default swap space so their iBoxx indices where used as benchmarks for a lot of bond funds.  While JNK is substantially similar and slightly cheaper, if your benchmark for your fund is "Markit iBoxx® USD Liquid High Yield Index" you likely use HYG for hedging not JNK.

Now, since the iBoxx index is more established it has a higher trading volume and might have a smaller bid/ask spread and could be cheaper to trade a lot even if its expense ratio is slightly higher.   Also, HYG tracks a slightly wider (junkier) universe in high-yield and still has a significantly lower turnover which could be appealing to some but also adds to the tracking error.

Comment: So this article actually claims that HYG has a lower tracking error than JNK: http://www.barrons.com/articles/junking-high-yield-etfs-not-all-funds-are-the-same-1447964796. What do you think?

Comment: I was using Schwab as a source.  I don't have access to read Barrons.  I would guess they both have fairly high tracking error because they both cover indices that are hard to track, but it wouldn't surprise me if the tracking error varies fairly wildly over different periods.